# New relic in React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, newrelic, apm, newrelic-platform

New relic integration via node APM service in React. and need to generate scripts under head tag before page render in a react application, actually need to monitor our website by integrating new-relic in react application.

Comment: Sounds cool but this is a forum not a service provider ;) What have you tried so far? Where did you get an error?

Comment: @johannchopin [SO is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.